# MATLAB Cubic Spline Coefficient HW

Tags: matlab, matrix, coefficients, cubic-spline

I am a distance learner and am currently going back and forth with my TA to no avail on this question. I was a mathematics undergrad student so I understand that mathematics behind a cubic spline however, I am very new to coding and am having trouble translating the math into code in MATLAB. The code I have is the sum total of what I translated from the Algorithm given to me in my text book and my back and forth with my TA.

Problem: Implement the cubic spline interpolation. Modify the algorithm such that your program outputs the table of the coefficients for the cubic spline polynomials.

The code is returning

```
A = 2.3000

    2.3000
```

which is no where near the number of coefficients that should be returned.

Code So Far:

```
%INPUT The total number of inputs, x, and f(x).

n=13;

x = [0.9,1.3,1.9,2.1,2.6,3.0,3.9,4.4,4.7,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0];

a = [1.3,1.5,1.85,2.1,2.6,2.7,2.4,2.15,2.05,2.1,2.25,2.3,2.25];

b=zeros(n,1)

c=zeros(n,1)

d=zeros(n,1)

%Step 1

for i = 1:n-1
        h(i) = x(i+1) - x(i);
end

%Step 2

for i = 2:n-1
        alpha(i) = (3/h(i))*(a(i+1) - a(i)) - (3/(h(i)-1))*(a(i) - a(i-1));
end

%Step 3

l(1) = 1; 
mu(1) = 0;
z(1) = 0;

%Step 4

for i = 2:n-1
    l(i) = 2*(x(i+1) - x(i-1)) - h(i-1)*mu(i-1);
    mu(i) = h(i)/l(i);
    z(i) = (alpha(i) - h(i-1)*z(i-1))/l(i);
end

%Step 5

l(n) = 1;
z(n) = 0;
c(n) = 0;

%Step 6

for j = n:n-1:1
    c(j) = z(j) - mu(j)*c(j+1);
    b(j) = (a(j+1) - a(j))/h(j) - h(j)*(c(j+1) + 2*c(j))/3;
    d(j) = (c(j+1) - c(j))/(3*h(j));
end

%OUTPUT (aj , bj , cj , dj for j = 0, 1, . . . , n - 1)

A(j) = [a(j),b(j),c(j),d(j)]
disp(A)
```

Comment: Well, you are using `b` and it does not exist. You can not index `b(j)` if `b` is non existent. If you look closely, MATLAB is telling you this, there is an orange wiggle in the letter or in the side of your code, describing the problem and the solution. Solution being: make it exist. For example `b=zeros(n,1)` is a way, where you create it and fill it with zeroes (not important, you are replacing them).

Comment: If you are not used to coding, a very good advice is to google your error codes. There are hundreds of people that had this problem before and it will take you less time to read a post than write one.